# HTMLAgilityPack and marshaling clicked signal

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to crawl an html document.

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

    htmlDoc.Load(@"C:\..\page.html");

    var hptexts = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");

    foreach (var hptext in hptexts)
    {
        string desc = hptext.Attributes["href"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(desc);
    }
```

This is the code i use, prints the 5-6 first links of the page and then shows up "Marshal clicked signal", what am i missing here?

**Edit 02/27/13**
Here is the html code that makes crawling stop

```
</a> </li> </ul> <span class="login-area"> <div id="p_p_id_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet_" class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet_  portlet-static portlet-static-end  " > <a id="p_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet"></a> <div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> <div class="portlet-body"> <!--p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/--><div id="A4925:j_idt5" style="display:none" title="text"><img id="A4925:j_idt6" src="/bon-portlet/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" alt="" /></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){statusDialog=new PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog("A4925:j_idt5",{autoOpen:false,minHeight:0,draggable:false,zIndex:9999,resizable:false,appendToBody:true,closable:false})});/*]]>*/</script><div id="A4925:j_idt7" style="display:none" title="text"> <form id="A4925:frmSendPassword" name="A4925:frmSendPassword" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> <input type="hidden" name="A4925:frmSendPassword" value="A4925:frmSendPassword" /> <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.encodedURL" value="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=2&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" /> <span id="A4925:myPanel2"> <p>text</p><table class="forgot"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <div></td> </tr> <tr> <td><div id="A4925:j_idt14" class="ui-messages ui-widget"></div></td> </tr> <tr> <td></div> <div> </div></td> </tr> <tr> <td> <div><label for="A4925:txtEmail2" class=""> Email</label><input id="A4925:txtEmail2" type="text" name="A4925:txtEmail2" maxlength="40" size="40" /> </div> <div><div id="A4925:msgFortxtEmail2"></div> </div></td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <div class="sendButton"><button id="A4925:j_idt24" name="A4925:j_idt24" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'A4925:frmSendPassword',source:'A4925:j_idt24',process:'A4925:myPanel2',update:'A4925:myPanel2'});return false;" type="submit">text</button><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/widget_A4925_j_idt24=new PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton("A4925:j_idt24",{});/*]]>*/</script> </div></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1oLiIQTArsSxRr7QkM0fPI7E4wzexgJX91sHDYgkXmRmY3Bi4cvITU9wSk0vyizwZOEsyilKLM/JzUioK7B0YQICnnANICgAxSwkDv6OJpZGpVUlFiWtuYmaOUWkRg3C0D9iCnMS8dD3/pKzU5BLrCeci5gsUa+YwMTBUFIB0FgBBCQMrWHdpIUMdAzNQlAnOYgXJw3nMdUUMuiAzK/TSEpNTi/WS83ML8vNS80r0Qj3DMlPLg/LzS1QCivILUotKKr1TK4sZoEAIaF8RAx/CPa55pbnIkkBHsOUkFpd4psADBqzOM68kNT21SOjRgiXfG9stmBgYPRlYyxJzSlOB5gkg1PmV5ialFrWtmSrLPeVBN8x7XCDP8cKDJiCxuBjuGajX+VADDlW6AgDM3QSPqwEAAA==" autocomplete="off" /> </form></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){loginDialog=new PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog("A4925:j_idt7",{autoOpen:false,minHeight:0,dialogClass:"modal",modal:true,zIndex:9900,resizable:false,appendToBody:true})});/*]]>*/</script> <script></script> <script>/*<![CDATA[*/PlayerClub.userName="";PlayerClub.token="";/*]]>*/</script> <form id="A4925:frmBonLogin" name="A4925:frmBonLogin" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" class="login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> <input type="hidden" name="A4925:frmBonLogin" value="A4925:frmBonLogin" /> <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.encodedURL" value="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=2&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" /> <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/refreshLogin=function(){PrimeFaces.ab({formId:"A4925:frmBonLogin",source:"A4925:j_idt27",process:"@all",update:"A4925:pnlLogin",params:arguments[0]})};/*]]>*/</script><span id="A4925:pageMessages"></span><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){widget_A4925_pageMessages=new PrimeFaces.widget.Growl("A4925:pageMessages",[])});/*]]>*/</script><span id="A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn"><table> <tbody> <tr> <td><input id="A4925:txtEmail" type="text" name="A4925:txtEmail" /></td> <td><input id="A4925:txtPass" type="password" name="A4925:txtPass" /></td> <td><button id="A4925:j_idt29" name="A4925:j_idt29" class="loginBtn" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'A4925:frmBonLogin',source:'A4925:j_idt29',process:'A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn',update:'A4925:pnlLogin A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn A4925:pageMessages',oncomplete:function(xhr, status, args){if(args.redirect != null) {                     PlayerClub.Events.notify({name : 'loggedIn'});                    }              ;}});return false;" type="submit">text</button><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/widget_A4925_j_idt29=new PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton("A4925:j_idt29",{});/*]]>*/</script></td> <td> <a class="forgotpwd" onclick="loginDialog.show()">text</a></td> <td>Β Β </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </span><span id="A4925:pnlLogin"></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1oLiIQTArsSxRr7QkM0fPI7E4wzexgJX91sHDYgkXmRmY3Bi4cvITU9wSk0vyizwZOEsyilKLM/JzUioK7B0YQICnnANICgAxSwkDv6OJpZGpVUlFiWtuYmaOUWkRg3C0D9iCnMS8dD3/pKzU5BLrCeci5gsUa+YwMTBUFIB0FgBBCQMrWHdpIUMdAzNQlAnOYgXJw3nMdUUMuiAzK/TSEpNTi/WS83ML8vNS80r0Qj3DMlPLg/LzS1QCivILUotKKr1TK4sZoEAIaF8RAx/CPa55pbnIkkBHsOUkFpd4psADBqzOM68kNT21SOjRgiXfG9stmBgYPRlYyxJzSlOB5gkg1PmV5ialFrWtmSrLPeVBN8x7XCDP8cKDJiCxuBjuGajX+VADDlW6AgDM3QSPqwEAAA==" autocomplete="off" /> </form> <script>/*<![CDATA[*/jQuery(document).ready(function(){if(false){refreshLogin()}});var myLoginListener=new PlayerClub.EventListener("loginListener");myLoginListener.onEvent=function(a){if(a.name=="loggedIn"){}else{if(a.name=="loggedOut"){refreshLogin()}}};PlayerClub.Events.add(myLoginListener);/*]]>*/</script> </div> </div> </div> </span> </div> </div> </div> <div id="wrapper-header"> <header id="banner" role="banner"> <hgroup id="heading"> <h1 class="company-title"> <a class="logo" href="http://www.website.com/el/web/guest/corporate" title="text website.com"></a> <div id="header_right" style="float:right;"> <div id="BannerWebContent"> <div id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_w9W4_" class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_  portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-journal-content " > <a id="p_56_INSTANCE_w9W4"></a> <div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> <div class="portlet-body"> <div class="journal-content-article" id="article_10132_10157_1794409_12.1"> <p style="text-align: right;"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itCvQgnTqD9sNyqKaBsNZOM6&amp;index=1" style="line-height: 1.4;" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=666cec6b-27b5-483a-9737-f760ddbca822&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361443806379" style="width: 120px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itD0C6mk7FhFtyzGJ7lxSkFz" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=44e791df-7011-406e-ab58-04caa1d3b904&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361373259040" style="width: 120px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itD0C6mk7FhFtyzGJ7lxSkFz&amp;index=1" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=edf1a342-48e3-4785-b845-4e3adae50c36&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247908" style="width: 75px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itBR11d2SBq52tBgIScoPIAd&amp;index=1" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=cd7445f3-3c3e-40aa-82f8-8101dea42892&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247908" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=35289fbe-9586-4fcf-841f-b7422ace31df&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1359117469851" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=b8457859-354f-4a70-b03b-895e0d836f8c&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1359117469851" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="link" target=""><img alt="RSS" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=56cc6300-0322-4845-bf88-0f6540b815ef&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247893" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="link"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=33b4f346-1490-48d0-86d9-719bd7b059fb&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361459169242" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a></p> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </h1> <h2 class="community-title"> <a href="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_auth=0xCQE4av&amp;p_p_id=49&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_count=1&amp;_49_struts_action=%2fmy_places%2fview&amp;_49_groupId=10157&amp;_49_privateLayout=false" title="text website.com"> <span>website.com</span> </a> </h2> <h3 class="page-title"> <span>text‚ &amp; text</span> </h3> </hgroup> <div id="navigation"> <div class="navigation-main-content"> <ul> <li class=""> <a href="link"  class="home"> <div><span>+</span></div> </a> </li> <li class="menu-seperator"><div></div></li> <li class="selected "> <a href="link" > text</a></a> </li> </ul> <span class="login-area"> <div id="p_p_id_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet_" class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet_  portlet-static portlet-static-end  " > <a id="p_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet"></a> <div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> <div class="portlet-body"> <!--p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/--><div id="A4925:j_idt5" style="display:none" title="text"><img id="A4925:j_idt6" src="/bon-portlet/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" alt="" /></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){statusDialog=new PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog("A4925:j_idt5",{autoOpen:false,minHeight:0,draggable:false,zIndex:9999,resizable:false,appendToBody:true,closable:false})});/*]]>*/</script><div id="A4925:j_idt7" style="display:none" title="text"> <form id="A4925:frmSendPassword" name="A4925:frmSendPassword" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> <input type="hidden" name="A4925:frmSendPassword" value="A4925:frmSendPassword" /> <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.encodedURL" value="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=2&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" /> <span id="A4925:myPanel2"> <p>text</p><table class="forgot"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <div></td> </tr> <tr> <td><div id="A4925:j_idt14" class="ui-messages ui-widget"></div></td> </tr> <tr> <td></div> <div> </div></td> </tr> <tr> <td> <div><label for="A4925:txtEmail2" class=""> Email</label><input id="A4925:txtEmail2" type="text" name="A4925:txtEmail2" maxlength="40" size="40" /> </div> <div><div id="A4925:msgFortxtEmail2"></div> </div></td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <div class="sendButton"><button id="A4925:j_idt24" name="A4925:j_idt24" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'A4925:frmSendPassword',source:'A4925:j_idt24',process:'A4925:myPanel2',update:'A4925:myPanel2'});return false;" type="submit">text</button><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/widget_A4925_j_idt24=new PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton("A4925:j_idt24",{});/*]]>*/</script> </div></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1oLiIQTArsSxRr7QkM0fPI7E4wzexgJX91sHDYgkXmRmY3Bi4cvITU9wSk0vyizwZOEsyilKLM/JzUioK7B0YQICnnANICgAxSwkDv6OJpZGpVUlFiWtuYmaOUWkRg3C0D9iCnMS8dD3/pKzU5BLrCeci5gsUa+YwMTBUFIB0FgBBCQMrWHdpIUMdAzNQlAnOYgXJw3nMdUUMuiAzK/TSEpNTi/WS83ML8vNS80r0Qj3DMlPLg/LzS1QCivILUotKKr1TK4sZoEAIaF8RAx/CPa55pbnIkkBHsOUkFpd4psADBqzOM68kNT21SOjRgiXfG9stmBgYPRlYyxJzSlOB5gkg1PmV5ialFrWtmSrLPeVBN8x7XCDP8cKDJiCxuBjuGajX+VADDlW6AgDM3QSPqwEAAA==" autocomplete="off" /> </form></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){loginDialog=new PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog("A4925:j_idt7",{autoOpen:false,minHeight:0,dialogClass:"modal",modal:true,zIndex:9900,resizable:false,appendToBody:true})});/*]]>*/</script> <script></script> <script>/*<![CDATA[*/PlayerClub.userName="";PlayerClub.token="";/*]]>*/</script> <form id="A4925:frmBonLogin" name="A4925:frmBonLogin" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" class="login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> <input type="hidden" name="A4925:frmBonLogin" value="A4925:frmBonLogin" /> <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.encodedURL" value="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?_bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet__facesViewId=%2fxhtml%2flogin.xhtml&amp;p_p_col_id=&amp;p_p_id=bonLoginPortlet_WAR_bonportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=2&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal" /> <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/refreshLogin=function(){PrimeFaces.ab({formId:"A4925:frmBonLogin",source:"A4925:j_idt27",process:"@all",update:"A4925:pnlLogin",params:arguments[0]})};/*]]>*/</script><span id="A4925:pageMessages"></span><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){widget_A4925_pageMessages=new PrimeFaces.widget.Growl("A4925:pageMessages",[])});/*]]>*/</script><span id="A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn"><table> <tbody> <tr> <td><input id="A4925:txtEmail" type="text" name="A4925:txtEmail" /></td> <td><input id="A4925:txtPass" type="password" name="A4925:txtPass" /></td> <td><button id="A4925:j_idt29" name="A4925:j_idt29" class="loginBtn" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'A4925:frmBonLogin',source:'A4925:j_idt29',process:'A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn',update:'A4925:pnlLogin A4925:pnlNotLoggedIn A4925:pageMessages',oncomplete:function(xhr, status, args){if(args.redirect != null) {                     PlayerClub.Events.notify({name : 'loggedIn'});                    }              ;}});return false;" type="submit">text</button><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/widget_A4925_j_idt29=new PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton("A4925:j_idt29",{});/*]]>*/</script></td> <td> <a class="forgotpwd" onclick="loginDialog.show()">text</a></td> <td>Β Β </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </span><span id="A4925:pnlLogin"></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1oLiIQTArsSxRr7QkM0fPI7E4wzexgJX91sHDYgkXmRmY3Bi4cvITU9wSk0vyizwZOEsyilKLM/JzUioK7B0YQICnnANICgAxSwkDv6OJpZGpVUlFiWtuYmaOUWkRg3C0D9iCnMS8dD3/pKzU5BLrCeci5gsUa+YwMTBUFIB0FgBBCQMrWHdpIUMdAzNQlAnOYgXJw3nMdUUMuiAzK/TSEpNTi/WS83ML8vNS80r0Qj3DMlPLg/LzS1QCivILUotKKr1TK4sZoEAIaF8RAx/CPa55pbnIkkBHsOUkFpd4psADBqzOM68kNT21SOjRgiXfG9stmBgYPRlYyxJzSlOB5gkg1PmV5ialFrWtmSrLPeVBN8x7XCDP8cKDJiCxuBjuGajX+VADDlW6AgDM3QSPqwEAAA==" autocomplete="off" /> </form> <script>/*<![CDATA[*/jQuery(document).ready(function(){if(false){refreshLogin()}});var myLoginListener=new PlayerClub.EventListener("loginListener");myLoginListener.onEvent=function(a){if(a.name=="loggedIn"){}else{if(a.name=="loggedOut"){refreshLogin()}}};PlayerClub.Events.add(myLoginListener);/*]]>*/</script> </div> </div> </div> </span> </div> </div> </div> <div id="wrapper-header"> <header id="banner" role="banner"> <hgroup id="heading"> <h1 class="company-title"> <a class="logo" href="http://www.website.com/el/web/guest/corporate" title="text website.com"></a> <div id="header_right" style="float:right;"> <div id="BannerWebContent"> <div id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_w9W4_" class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_  portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-journal-content " > <a id="p_56_INSTANCE_w9W4"></a> <div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> <div class="portlet-body"> <div class="journal-content-article" id="article_10132_10157_1794409_12.1"> <p style="text-align: right;"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itCvQgnTqD9sNyqKaBsNZOM6&amp;index=1" style="line-height: 1.4;" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=666cec6b-27b5-483a-9737-f760ddbca822&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361443806379" style="width: 120px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itD0C6mk7FhFtyzGJ7lxSkFz" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=44e791df-7011-406e-ab58-04caa1d3b904&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361373259040" style="width: 120px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itD0C6mk7FhFtyzGJ7lxSkFz&amp;index=1" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=edf1a342-48e3-4785-b845-4e3adae50c36&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247908" style="width: 75px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/&amp;list=PLMiMYkQZ3itBR11d2SBq52tBgIScoPIAd&amp;index=1" target="_blank"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=cd7445f3-3c3e-40aa-82f8-8101dea42892&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247908" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=35289fbe-9586-4fcf-841f-b7422ace31df&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1359117469851" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=b8457859-354f-4a70-b03b-895e0d836f8c&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1359117469851" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="link" target=""><img alt="RSS" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=56cc6300-0322-4845-bf88-0f6540b815ef&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361282247893" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a><a href="link"><img alt="text" src="/image/image_gallery?uuid=33b4f346-1490-48d0-86d9-719bd7b059fb&amp;groupId=10157&amp;t=1361459169242" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></a></p> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </h1> <h2 class="community-title"> <a href="http://www.website.com/web/guest/test-draw-results?p_auth=giN14rWX&amp;p_p_auth=0xCQE4av&amp;p_p_id=49&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_count=1&amp;_49_struts_action=%2fmy_places%2fview&amp;_49_groupId=10157&amp;_49_privateLayout=false" title="text website.com"> <span>website.com</span> </a> </h2> <h3 class="page-title"> <span>text‚ &amp; text</span> </h3> </hgroup> <div id="navigation"> <div class="navigation-main-content"> <ul> <li class=""> <a href="link"  class="home"> <div><span>+</span></div> </a> </li> <li class="menu-seperator"><div></div></li> <li class="selected "> <a href="link" > text</a>
```

Until this one it prints everything correctly.

Comment: what do u actually want..?? You want all href values of all hyperlinks..?

Comment: We would need the page.html source. Please copy it somewhere. Also, you should dump the full exception stack; not just the final message.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the html chunk you put in the question. Do you have a full html page or file or url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlDocument doc= new HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(@"C:\..\page.html");

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if(node.OuterHtml.Contains("href"))
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

EDIT: I edited my code now it will work. Your problem was that some **a** tags didn't have **href** attribute

Comment: With both codes i get the same error after a few links. I deleted the next line after the last link and it continued. The thing is that this line was javascript, how could i continue my crawling without deleting any lines?

Comment: Please post your html code - if you don't want to show some parts of text replace them with bla bla bla or something

Comment: This is not a good solution, in 99.9% of the try..catch in similar situations are easy to avoid, and should be avoided, since they hurt performance, among other things. You should first check if there's an attribute "href" before trying to get it's value.

Comment: We can check if it has an `href` attribute using Xpath like `//a[@href]`. This will only select elements those contains href

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

htmlDoc.Load(@"C:\..\page.html");

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(t => t.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("#"));
// u can remove LINQ extension method Where() if u want to include # links too


foreach (HtmlNode hptext in nodes)
{
    string desc = hptext.Attributes["href"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(desc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
It doesn't print any link and i get the same error "Marshaling clicked signal".
Yes, i want all href values.

Comment: @NickMadison- can u upload your html file `page.html` somewhere..? I will try it myself and will give u a solution very soon.

Comment: @NickMadison I have just updated my code. Try it now and tell me if it is working or not

Comment: @NickMadison You could also use Xpath for this. I have just updated my answer